# Sortable get element index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I got this html code:

```
<div id="pages">
    <div id="page1"></div>
    <div id="page2"></div>
    <div id="page3"></div>
    <div id="page4"></div>
</div>
```

Just for testing I would like to show the elements index on sorting the grid:

```
$( "#pages" ).sortable({

    sort: function(event,ui){
        console.log($('#pages').index(ui.item));
    }
});
```

The returned index is the index where the dragged element was on starting the drag.
If I move the code in the stop/update event, I receive the correct index.
My problem is, that on dragging the visual notice (flip between other divs) is an other that the index returns and I need to change the css margins of the elements.

How to get the correct order while dragging the element?

TIA
frgtv10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access to the current index of the dragged item you need to use `ui.placeholder` item.

```
$( "#pages" ).sortable({
    helper: "clone",
    sort: function(event, ui) {
        console.log($(ui.placeholder).index());
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle here (jQuery 1.8.2, jQueryUI 1.9.2)](http://jsfiddle.net/h33v3/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I need the whole list, I have to go through the elements (each) and add the placeholder index to the list, correct? Or is there a better way?

Comment: If you need the whole list, yes you need to parse it with `.each`.
If you just parse it with 'div' selector, placeholder item will be one of them.